# Does a pointer to a reference point to the adress of the reference or the value?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Imagine the following scenario:

```
class ABC
{ 
  public: 
  int abc;
};

ABC& modifyABC(ABC& foo)
{
  foo.abc+=1337;
  return foo;
}

void saveABC(ABC& bar, std::vector<ABC*>& list)
{
  list.push_back(&modifyABC(bar));
}

int main()
{
  ABC foobar;
  std::vector<ABC*> ABCList;
  saveABC(foobar,ABCList);
  return 0;
}
```

modifyABC() returns a reference to ABC(which is internally some sort of pointer too AFAIK). Does the "adress of" & operator now return a pointer to the adress of the reference or the actually object behind the reference?

Comment: In C++, there is no such thing as a pointer to a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `modifyABC()` returns a reference to `ABC` (*which is internally some sort of pointer too AFAIK*)

**Not exactly**.

Pointers are objects (variables) that require some storage and hold in that storage the address in memory of another object. **References are pure *aliases***, like alternative names. In theory, they do not require any storage at all.

Per Paragraph 8.3.2/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage (3.7).

So a pointer to a reference is actually a pointer to the referenced object, and **any operation done on a reference** (apart from the act of binding it to an object upon initialization) **is actually done on the object for which the reference is an alias**.

Comment: Every compiler I know actually implements references as pointers, so under the hood, they do have an address and occupy space.  On the other hand, the required semantics of references are such that you cannot see these implementation details.

Comment: Wonderfull, thats what i wanted to know!

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with the last sentence of your question ("*a pointer to the adress of the reference*"?)

What can be said is that `modifyABC()` takes a reference to an `ABC`, and returns exactly the same reference. No copy of the object is made.

The overall effect of your code is that the address of `foobar` is appended to `ABCList`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the "adress of" & operator now return a pointer to the adress of the reference or the actually object behind the reference?

In C++, references, as such, do not have their *own* addresses. So address of a reference means address of the object the reference is referring to.

```
X x; 
X &r = x; //reference
X *p = &r; //same as &x
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Easy question i know for u guys, i couldnt find an exact answer for this so far.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you do with a reference (including taking its address)
is the equivalent of doing it to the referred to object.  In
C++, a reference itself is *not* an object, does not necessarily
occupy space in memory, and does not have an address.

Answer (score 0):

A reference and a pointer are two different concepts. You may think of a reference as an alias to an **existing object**. So just like an alias to an alias is again alias of the original, here the return value of modifyABC() is again a reference to the original object. Taking the pointer to a reference always return the address of the object you have a reference of.